# Load dotenv and polyfills in brunch

Tags: javascript, brunch

I'm trying to make some boilerplates for my react apps with the build tool `brunch`. It's pretty easy to kickstart but i need some little things to make my development more complete. One of those things is environment variables.

I tried some ideas but nothing works. Things like use the `entryPoints` to load a config JS file executing the functions:

**brunch-config.js**

```
exports.files = {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'dependencies.js': /^(?!app\/)/,
      'bundle.js': /^app\//
    },
    entryPoints: {
      'app/confs.js': 'bundle.js'
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {
    joinTo: 'app.css'
  },
};

exports.plugins = {
  babel: { presets: ['latest', 'react'] }
};
```

**confs.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('whatwg-fetch');
```

But for now, nothing works... can someone give me some idea?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

I changed some things in my config and structure, the idea is still the same, load `polifylls` and `env` variables in the app bootstrap.

Now `confs.js` is `init.js`and isn't compiled into `bundle.js`but in it's own file into `public/`.

The code inside is the same, and the `brunch-config.js` is:

```
exports.files = {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'dependencies.js': /^(?!app\/)/,
      'bundle.js': 'app/**/*[!init].js', // all but not init.js
      'init.js': 'app/init.js' // put init.js in it's own file into public/
    }
  },
  stylesheets: {
    joinTo: 'app.css'
  },
};

exports.plugins = {
  babel: { presets: ['latest', 'react'] },
  sass: {
    options: {
      includePaths: ['node_modules/normalize-css/']
    }
  }
};
```

**BUT** the compiled `init.js` is empty in his `require.register()`, no matter what code i put inside my file:

```
require.register("init.js", function(exports, require, module) {
"use strict";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
<script>require('confs');</script>
```

in the index.html.

Normally, you just require one initial Javascript file from the HTML file. In this Javascript file, you require the other software packages. This is needed so somehow make the dependencies between the packages explicit.

Comment: Tried this but doesn't works. The confs structure is the same but this time i called it before in the `index.html` and nothing happens. I'm trying another approach, i will update this.